# How can I use a validation to require a certain number of instances (of another class) to be associated with an instance?

Tags: ruby, class, model, instance

I am using plain Ruby. I have a "Restaurant" class that needs to be associated with at least 10 instances of a "Dish" class.

```
    class Restaurant<ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :dishes
       validates :dishes, :length=>{:minimum=>10}
    end
```

requires a dish to have a minimum of 10 characters, rather than an array of associated dishes to have a length of at least 10.

Comment: `ActiveRecord` is not part of Ruby, so it's not clear what you mean when you say you are using "plain Ruby".

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. Your question needs more detail and information. What is the problem you've encountered? We can't run your code to replicate a problem. SO is to help solve problems with code, not to provide documentation or tutorials; You need to research and try things and then ask when you encounter a problem.